# Foundation 5 Masonry like Grid

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation-5

How can I manage to do this (the image) kind of layout with Foundation framework 5? If not possible I really like vanilla CSS option. Javascript is last option. And it should be responsive.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is pure CSS sample for your Grid,
You can check it online : https://jsfiddle.net/5peu1qef/

```
.block1 { margin: 0 1.5% 10px 0; width: 60%; float:left; background: #e85959; height: 300px; } 
.block2 { margin: 0 1.5% 10px 0; width: 29.3%; float:left; background: #e85959; height: 145px; }
.block3 { margin: 0 1.5% 10px 0; width: 60%; float:left; background: #e85959; height: 145px; }
```

Comment: It doesn't do the job the way i wanted to but i did not ask clearly.